# HTTPS Error while refreshing the page in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-error-boundary

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl4Bh.jpg)We have developed our frontend in ReactJs. The website is showing HTTPS error after refreshing any page of the website.

What could be the possible error and how to resolve it?

Comment: What's the HTTP response status and error message?

Comment: I have added the error's screenshot. Please have a look.